# How to create dynamic dictionary and add list content to it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created the below logic to add list to a dictionary in Python it works fine

```
>>> dict ={}
>>> dict ={"key":[]}
>>> dict['key']
[]
>>> dict['key'].append('a')
>>> dict['key']
['a']
```

When I try to Implement same thing while parsing the JSON and creating dynamic dictionary based on certain it failed to add in the List and report as NoneType

```
import json
json_data="""{
   "data":[
      {
         "package_path":"/bin/bash",
         "package_type":"rpm"
      },
      {
         "package_path":"com.test3",
         "package_type":"java"
      },
      {
         "package_path":"com.test",
         "package_type":"java"
      }
   ]
}
"""

j_dict = json.loads(json_data)

dict2 = {}
for vuln in j_dict['data']:
   package_type = vuln['package_type']
   package_path = vuln['package_path']

   if package_type in dict2:
      dict2 ={package_type:[]}
   else:
      dict2[package_type].append(package_path)
```

Throws error

```
 % python ~/Desktop/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    dict2[package_type].append(package_path)
KeyError: u'rpm'
```

Expecting output like

`dict2 {"java":['com.test3','com.test2'],"rpm":['/bin/bash']}`

Comment: You code says if `rpm` isn't in `dict2`, assume it already has an entry with a list and append to it. Which of course fails.

Comment: You want `if package_type not in dict2:`; as is, you replace it only if it already existed, and try to use it when it doesn't exist. Voting to close as typo. Side-note: Why are you writing new code in Python 2?!? It's been EOL since the beginning of the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault` to create empty list if the key is not found inside the dictionary. For example:

```
import json
json_data="""{
   "data":[
      {
         "package_path":"/bin/bash",
         "package_type":"rpm"
      },
      {
         "package_path":"com.test3",
         "package_type":"java"
      },
      {
         "package_path":"com.test",
         "package_type":"java"
      }
   ]
}
"""

j_dict = json.loads(json_data)
out = {}
for vuln in j_dict['data']:
    out.setdefault(vuln['package_type'], []).append(vuln['package_path'])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'rpm': ['/bin/bash'], 'java': ['com.test3', 'com.test']}
```

Answer (score 2):

[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) can be used here.

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

json_data = """{
   "data":[
      {
         "package_path":"/bin/bash",
         "package_type":"rpm"
      },
      {
         "package_path":"com.test3",
         "package_type":"java"
      },
      {
         "package_path":"com.test",
         "package_type":"java"
      }
   ]
}
"""

j_dict = json.loads(json_data)
data = defaultdict(list)
for entry in j_dict['data']:
    data[entry['package_type']].append(entry['package_path'])
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'rpm': ['/bin/bash'], 'java': ['com.test3', 'com.test']})
```

Comment: That: `if package_type in dict2:  dict2 ={package_type:[]}`

Answer (score 1):

You have your `if` statement slightly wrong:

```
if package_type in dict2:
   dict2 ={package_type:[]}
else:
   dict2[package_type].append(package_path)
```

Should be:

```
if package_type not in dict2:
   dict2[package_type] = []

dict2[package_type].append(package_path)
```

You were saying, if a key was in the dictionary, replace the whole dictionary with a single key and a list as the value.

In the `else` clause you were saying, if the key doesn't exist, fetch the value for that key, assume it's a list, and append to it. Which fails.

This idiom of either adding  value if it doesn't exist or using the existing value is so common, there are a couple of different ways of doing it built into python and its libraries.

[**`dict.setdefault`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) will either set a new default value for a key, or return the existing value if it exists. I find its call syntax ugly:

```
dict2.setdefault(package_type, []).append(package_path)
```

This sets the key's value to `[]` if it doesn't exist, returns it, and then you can append to the list as it exists in the dictionary.

An alternative that I prefer is to use [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), which is a dictionary that automatically creates a default value when a key doesn't already exist:

```
dict2 = defaultdict(list)

dict2[package_type].append(package_path)
```